# Espresso click on specific word in TextView

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I am running some espresso tests, and I have some links in a block of text which, when clicked, will open popup windows with data in them. However, I cannot get Espresso to click on the specific text, so I can;t even open these windows to test them.

Have tried stuff like

```
onView(withId(R.id.textView(matches(withText(containsString("45"))))));
```

but this doesn't work and just hangs up the test for quite some time.